# OBJECTIVEFLICKR: systemconfiguration.h not found

Tags: xcode, flickr

I'm implementing `ObjectiveFlickr` into my project and I'm very VERY new to all of this (C language and Xcode included).

I managed to fix a few compile errors and I'm down to this one that just popped up after I added some supporting files to get rid of the other errors:

> systemconfiguration/systemconfiguration.h file not found

I have no idea what this means and have done much searching online before posting here, but the only resolution to another poster's issue was to re-install Xcode. I'm sort of doubting that will solve this problem as I've had no issue with Xcode up until this error.

Can anyone spare a tip or two in layman's terms to help me get past this? I've been searching for 24 hours and the only link to the Apple Developer forums isn't working, go figure.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

XCode can be very picky about where to look at in terms of header files.

If you got yourself a .framework folder, then click in your project, choose "Build Settings", then look for one called "Header Search Paths". Put the framework's path in there, and change the box on the right from "non-recursive" to "recursive". This should get the build going, and works for almost all third-party libraries.

If, on the other hand, you're trying to compile the library with your app, double-check to see if you didn't forgot to include some file in your XCode project, or if it is not marked for compilation in the project settings (.h files do not count, but maybe the source of your problem are some extra .c or .m that shouldn't be there).

If all else fails, since XCode projects compile into a "flat" directory tree, you could try removing the folder indicator from the #include: from "systemconfiguration/systemconfiguration.h" to "systemconfiguration.h", from the files where the .h is called. This worked in some cases of mine.

Comment: I'm going to look into this as soon as I get home. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework in iOS called "Systemconfiguration.framework". Add it may help a lot. 
Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had blanks for some reason in my code around the header decaration

```
 #import < SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h >
```

I removed them and it worked.